# Differentiation of a series of function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

If $f(x) = \frac{x-1}{4}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{12}+\frac{(x-1)^5}{20}+\frac{(x-1)^7}{28}\ldots$ where, $0 <x<2$ then find the derivative of $f(x)$

Please guide how to proceed for this.

This is an infinite series..

Comment: That is a simple sum, differentiate term by term. Or what exactly is stopping you?

Answer (score 5):

Since the problem is a power series, we must first write it in summation notation, and then differentiate term by term within its radius of convergence.  Note we can write the power series as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^{2n+1}}{8n+4}$$
Now, we apply the ratio test
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(x-1)^{2(n+1)+1}}{8(n+1)+4}\frac{8n+4}{(x-1)^{2n+1}}\right|=(x-1)^2<1\Longrightarrow 0<x<2$$
Now we can actually show that the interval of convergence is $0\le x<2$, but differentiating term by term is only valid in the interior of the interval of convergence.  What does it mean to 'differentiate term by term?'  It means for $0<x<2$, the following equality holds
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-1)^{2n+1}}{8n+4}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(x-1)^{2n+1}}{8n+4}$$

Now all you need to do is compute the derivative on the inside of the sum (treating $n$ as a constant).

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**: If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x$, then
$$
(f+g)'(x)=f'(x)+g'(x),
$$
and if $a$ is a constant, then
$$
(af)'(x)=a\cdot f'(x)
$$
If $g$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(x)$ then 
$$
(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x).
$$
And lastly if $f(x)=x^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f'(x)=n\cdot x^{n-1}$.

These are all the necessary tools to know in order for you to find the derivative.

Comment: But this is a power series!